# Scrapy Results are Repeating, problem with for loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm attempting to extract review data from a popular review aggregator. I'm running into an issue with the data being returned. Essentially the for loop "for review in reviews" is just extracting the first item in the list regardless of the position in the iteration. For example, a page with 20 reviews, I'll just get the information of the first review repeated 20 times.
I apologize for the html tags... it didn't make it easy...

```
def parse_gym_reviews_page(self, response):
        reviews = response.xpath('//li [@class="lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-b3__373c0__342DA border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]')
        gym = response.xpath('//h1[@class="lemon--h1__373c0__2ZHSL heading--h1__373c0__dvYgw undefined heading--inline__373c0__10ozy"]/text()').extract_first()
        about = response.xpath('//div [@class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc margin-b1__373c0__1khoT border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]/p/span//text()').extract_first()
        region = response.xpath('//p [@class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-"]/text()').extract_first()
        avg_rating = float(response.xpath('//span [@class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__3JqBP border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]/div/@aria-label').extract_first().split()[0])
        
        for review in reviews:
            user_name = review.xpath('//div [@class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]//a [@class="lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--inherit__373c0__3dzpk link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE"]/text()').extract_first()
            user_id = review.xpath('//div [@class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]//a [@class="lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--inherit__373c0__3dzpk link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE"]/@href').extract_first().partition("=")[2]
            rating = int(review.xpath('//div [@class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc arrange-unit__373c0__o3tjT arrange-unit-grid-column--8__373c0__2dUx_ border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]//div/@aria-label').extract_first().split()[0])
            text = review.xpath('//div [@class ="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc arrange-unit__373c0__o3tjT arrange-unit-grid-column--8__373c0__2dUx_ border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"]//p [@class= "lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz comment__373c0__3EKjH text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-"]/span [@class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G raw__373c0__3rKqk"]/text()').extract_first()
            reviewer_date = review.xpath('//span [@class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--mid__373c0__jCeOG text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-"]/text()').extract_first()

            
            item = YelpItem()
            item["gym"] = gym
            item["about"] = about
            item["region"] = region
            item["num_review"] = num_review
            item["avg_rating"] = avg_rating
            item["user_name"] = user_name
            item["user_id"] = user_id
            item["rating"] = rating
            item["text"] = text
            item["reviewer_date"] = reviewer_date
            yield item
```

Comment: What is `YelpItem()`?

Comment: The reason all results are the same is that you're just running the exact same XPath queries again and again - there's no reason to expect a different result the second time you call `review.xpath(<some expression>).extract_first()`

Comment: OHH! Yes. I forgot to add the "." before the <some path>. Thank you!